# Install MySQL in the Debian Jessie (8)

Tags: debian, mysql

I'm new in Linux, freshly installed a Debian Jessie (8) OS and need to work with MySQL. The hostname is,

```
hostname -f
```

It prints, `debian8`

When I type in the terminal,

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

I get the output back,

```
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient18:amd64              install
mysql-client-5.5                install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-server                    install
mysql-server-5.5                install
mysql-server-core-5.5               install
php5-mysql                  install
```

When I type in the terminal,

```
sudo apt-cache show mysql
```

The output is,

```
N: Unable to locate package mysql
E: No packages found
chaklader@debian8:/home/cx-components$
```

When I type in the terminal,

```
locate mysql
```

The output is,

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libmysqllo.so
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysql
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/mysqladmin
/usr/share/nmap/nselib/mysql.lua
/usr/share/nmap/nselib/data/mysql-cis.audit
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-audit.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-brute.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-databases.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-dump-hashes.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-empty-password.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-enum.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-info.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-query.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-users.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-variables.nse
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122.nse
```

When I type in the terminal,
    `which mysql`

No output is there.

When I type in the terminal,

```
mysql -u root -p
```

The output is,

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Is the MySQL is installed in the OS and if not how do I install?

Update:

As it was suggested, the MySQL server was not started. So, I start the server with the command,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

The output is provided below,

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
 failed!
```

It error was suggest to look for more detailed informations with associated commands.

I type the terminal,

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
```

I get the output provided,

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-12-17 21:10:21 +06; 1min 10s ago
  Process: 28321 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 17 21:09:50 debian8 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql .....
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: 0 processes alive and '/usr...
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: [61B blob data]
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: error: 'Can't connect to lo...
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: Check that mysqld is runnin...
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: 
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 mysql[28321]: Starting MySQL database server: mysql...d!
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, ...=1
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the...n.
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Secondly, I type the command for the `journalctl` provided below,

```
sudo journalctl -xn
```

The outout is,

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2017-12-17 10:33:35 +06, end at Sun 2017-12-17 21:12:02 +06
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 mysql[28321]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . .
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysq
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 sudo[28307]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for 
Dec 17 21:11:32 debian8 sudo[29437]: chaklader : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/chaklader
Dec 17 21:11:32 debian8 sudo[29437]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for 
Dec 17 21:11:32 debian8 sudo[29437]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for 
Dec 17 21:12:02 debian8 sudo[29539]: chaklader : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/chaklader
Dec 17 21:12:02 debian8 sudo[29539]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for 
lines 1-18/18 (END)
```

So, basically, the first thing to do is to run the MySQL server properly.

I have also tried to run the server like,

```
sudo systemctl start mysql.serivce
```

The output provided,

```
Failed to start mysql.serivce.service: Unit mysql.serivce.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

What steps do I need to take for that?

`Note:`

As asked in the comment, at the time I execute the command,

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service -l
```

I get the output like,

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-12-17 21:10:21 +06; 14min ago
  Process: 28321 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 17 21:09:50 debian8 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: [61B blob data]
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 /etc/init.d/mysql[29152]: 
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 mysql[28321]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Dec 17 21:10:21 debian8 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

What I primarily need to do is to migarte a database with the command,

```
/home/cx-components/cx-admin/app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

I get the output like,

```
                    Application Migrations                    

  [PDOException]                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)  

doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--configuration[="..."]] [--db-configuration[="..."]] [--db="..."] [--em="..."] [version]
```

What is the issue here?

As mentioned in the comment, I corrected the typo and run the command again, 
    sudo systemctl start mysql.service

The output is here,

```
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

Comment: Perhaps try following an install guide like this one: https://linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-8/

Comment: Please run `sudo systemctl status mysql.service -l`, that is, add the `-l` flag to see the ellipsized parts (all the `...`) in full.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately it doesn't show anything interesting. Try to find the logs. It might be somewhere in `/var/log/mysql` (I don't have a Debian around to verify the exact location)

Comment: @roaima Thanks for catching out. It still hasn't started and provided the clues for detailed error stacks.

Comment: anyone knows how do I connect the `MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output of `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql`,
MySQL (both the client tools and the server) are installed.

The error message you get when running `mysql` suggests that the MySQL service is not running.
You can start it with:

```
sudo service mysql start
# or: sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: hello, its good to know the client and the server both are installed. I tried to run the server as mentioned and it failed. I have provided the detailed error messages in the updated answer.